# Is there a name for this function or a concept similar to it?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, dynamical-systems, exponentiation, collatz-conjecture

I'm wondering if anyone has heard or seen a function that looks or behaves like this one.

### $$f\left(x\right)=\frac{x-b^{\left(\operatorname{floor}\left(\log_{b}x\right)\right)}}{b^{\left(\operatorname{floor}\left(\log_{b}x\right)\ +\ 1\right)}-b^{\left(\operatorname{floor}\left(\log_{b}x\right)\right)}}$$

'b' is a constant we choose. I've been calling this the "Proportional Power Ratio of x, base b", but I wonder if it goes by another name.

Here is a link to a Desmos graph where you can play with it and vary the base b. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/obedfxwb6l

Essentially the values get "smeared out' between powers of b.

Here is a graph of f(x) over integers in the interval [2, 256] where b is equal to 2:

[f(x) over integers in the interval [2, 256] where b is equal to 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3wES.png)

---

If you're more interested in the application of this, I posted an article on Medium about how I've been using this function to explore the Collatz Conjecture:

https://medium.com/@vardthomas/the-collatz-conjecture-a-new-perspective-on-an-old-problem-f4bca7ff675a

Comment: If not, we can start calling it "the Thomas function".

Comment: @Dan I like it - rolls off of the tongue better than "Proportional Power Ratio of x, base b" :)

Comment: @dthomas . Nice to see that you have humor . You could (probably even should) occasionally call it "the function the honor I have to bear its name". Esp. when you are talking on conferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\floor{\operatorname{floor}}$

Let $\#x$ denote the number of digits that are needed to represent $x\in\Bbb N$ to base $b$, then

$$\#x = 1 + \floor (\log_b x)$$

and $b^{\#x-1}$ is the natural number $10\cdots0$ in base $b$ that has the same number of digits like $x$ in base $b$.  Then

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{x-b^{\floor(\log_b x)}}{b^{\floor(\log_b x) + 1}-b^{\floor(\log_b x)}} \\
&= \frac {x-b^{\#x-1}}{b^{\#x} - b^{\#x-1}} \\
&= \frac 1{b-1} \cdot \left(\frac{x}{b^{\#x-1}} -1\right) \\
&\stackrel{(*)}= \frac{x}{b^{\#x-1}} -1 \tag 1
\end{align}$$

where in $(*)$ we ignore the constant factor of $1/(b-1)$.

The remaining formula $(1)$ then can be statet as:

> Take a natural number and insert a decimal point after the most significant digit, and then subtract$\ 1$.

For example is base 3, we'd have: `21001201 → 2.1001201 → 1.1001201`

One could also rephrase it as

> A relative measure of how far away a number is from the smallest number with the same number of digits.

Dunno for what's that good for, though...

Comment: Thank you for the intuition behind this! That's an interesting observation. I was thinking of it more as "A relative measure of how far a number 'n' is from the biggest power of 'b' that is still less than 'n'. The reason this is interesting to explore in terms of the Collatz Conjecture is that you all powers of 2 go straight to zero.

In this function, F(2^n) base_2 is always equal to zero. So my thinking was to apply the same kind of operation to other numbers and see what happens.